# Do I have to define function type when trying to fit a curve to my data?

Tags: python

I am working on experimental data which are sets of scalar values for x and y. I need to fit a function to this experimental data. The problem is, that the function shape will change signifficantly for each data set I have to investigate. That would force me to modify the code each time (assuming this time it can be expressed as a polynomial function, next time a sine and so on) seems suboptimal. What I need to get is the formula of the estimated function which is necessary for further analysis.
Is there any way of obtaining the fitted function formula without having to know function shape in advance?

Comment: If I understand you would like choosing the model according to the data and then fit the free parameters in this model. That is completely out of topic of any minimization/optimization algorithm (the problem is  even not clearly defined). You must turn to machine learning and bayesian methods, you may like the scikit-learn module (http://scikit-learn.org).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this module.